# What special reserved domain could I use for virtual organization private network?

Tags: vpn, dns

Suppose we have a inner-facing network that spans several geographical jurisdiction - this network can only accessed from our offices with special HSM installed, and we want to enable domain-name-based HTTPS connection with a private CA to enhance the effectiveness of access control.

What root (or starting) domain is most appropriate for this purpose?

- `home.arpa` Don't seem to be appropriate as it's for Residential LAN.
- `10.in-addr.arpa.` and `168.192.in-addr.arpa.` seems applicable to us, except it has numerical components and requires special DNS configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put: if you require no connectivity from the outside and keep everything private permanently you'd want to select a TLD or SLD/TLD combination that isn't used and isn't likely to appear.

<s>The standard procedure is to use the reserved *.local* TLD and something along *companyname.local*.</s> (*.local* is actually reserved for link-local name resolution - RFC 6762 - but you don't have to use that - you might need to make sure that all nodes are OK with that TLD though [thx Marc].) [edit] It seems this procedure is obsolete... For internal use, a subdomain of a publicly registered domain is recommended (e.g. *corp.companyname.tld*).

A CA service doesn't require a domain of its own, so you can also use any DNS name from your internal DNS like *ca.companyname.local*.

Do NOT use anything that's already used elsewhere, including *.arpa*.

If you do consider public availability you simply register the domain in some available TLD and use it as you like.

Comment: As you point out, `.local` is reserved for link local name resolution, and I think that's for good reasons. I've come across mDNS implementations that check for unicast DNS resolvability of `.local`.  If `.local`'s SOA could be resolved, the given mDNS implementation threw an errror and stopped itself. It took me a while to get my ISP understand the problem and to fix that in the recursive DNS servers they assigned via DHCP or PPP.  I suggest: Consider `.local` in unicast DNS only for _very_ well controlled environments, where end systems name resolution behaviour is thoroughly understood

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi Agreed - while it's seeing widespread use I haven't come across a problem with it though. For internal use, I like *companyname.int* better since you can even register it normally (which you might not need if you don't care about a collision with some namesake).

Comment: To repeat what @Marc'netztier'Luethi has said. *.local* has a specific defined purpose. Using it for anything other than that purpose is a mistake. Unfortunately, "just use .local" is all over the place. It's the same level of BS as all the sites using 224.0.0.1 in multicast "examples".

Comment: If you're certain you don't want to register under some top-level domain, you could consider the reserved two-letter codes of ISO 3166-1 (`AA`, `QM-QZ`, `XA-XZ`, and `ZZ`) which are for user assignment (as "countries"); I believe IANA has them reserved as ccTLDs (but I'd check before implementing!).