# Cisco IOS: DNS Servers via DHCP

Tags: dhcp, dns, cisco-ios-15, ios-xe

Simple question: I have following switch configuration:

```
interface Vlan1
 ip address dhcp
end

ip domain-lookup
```

I receive and IP and DNS servers along with it from our DHCP server. At least Windows clients in the same network, do. So i want to use DNS lookups, but the switch does not use the dns servers. What am i missing?

```
Switch#ping swinf03
*Feb 10 16:48:57.041: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console02
% Unrecognized host or address, or protocol not running.
```

Using the FQDN (even though, DNS suffix should be provided within the DHCP options) i cant get a response:

```
Switch#ping swinf03.company.local
% Unrecognized host or address, or protocol not running.
```

If i check what DNS servers are configured, i get following:

```
Switch#show ip dns servers 

   IP            VRF      TTL(s)   RTT(ms)  RTO(ms)  EDNS  DNSSEC  RECURSION
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
255.255.255.255           817      1000     4000      Yes    Yes     Yes
```

Platform is a IOS-XE Cisco 9200 switch.

Comment: Really, you do not want to configure your network infrastructure devices with DHCP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some options the client can request when IOS XE (and vanilla IOS, too) is a DHCP client.

I dont' have a Catalyst 9k at hand to test, but some of it might be in there, too

This is from a CSR 1000v (IOS XE at a prehistoric 03.13.06.S, resp. 15.4(3)S6 )

```
CSR1Kv-RTR1(config-if)#ip dhcp client request ?
  classless-static-route  Classless static route (121)
  dns-nameserver          DNS nameserver (6)
  domain-name             Domain name (15)
  netbios-nameserver      NETBIOS nameserver (44)
  router                  Default router option (3)
  static-route            Static route option (33)
  tftp-server-address     TFTP server address (150)
  vendor-specific         Vendor specific option (43)
  <cr>
```

You might want to check if your Catalyst supports any of these as well.

After setting this (some of which seems to be default, i.e. will disappear from the config)

```
interface GigabitEthernet3
 description *** mgmt interface ***
 ip address dhcp
 ip dhcp client request domain-name
 ip dhcp client request dns-nameserver
 ip dhcp client request router
 negotiation auto
```

... IOS-XE on the CSR came up with this:

```
CSR1Kv-RTR1#show dhcp lease
Temp IP addr: 172.19.41.0  for peer on Interface: GigabitEthernet3
Temp  sub net mask: 255.255.254.0
   DHCP Lease server: 172.19.40.1, state: 5 Bound
   DHCP transaction id: 1BE
   Lease: 691200 secs,  Renewal: 345600 secs,  Rebind: 604800 secs
Temp default-gateway addr: 172.19.40.1
   Next timer fires after: 3d23h
   Retry count: 0   Client-ID: cisco-5254.004b.a9ec-Gi3
   Client-ID hex dump: 636973636F2D353235342E303034622E
                       613965632D476933
   Hostname: CSR1Kv-RTR1
```

... and this:

```
CSR1Kv-RTR1#show dhcp server
   DHCP server: ANY (255.255.255.255)
    Leases:   2
    Offers:   2      Requests: 2     Acks : 2     Naks: 0
    Declines: 0      Releases: 3     Query: 0     Bad: 0
    VRF: global
    DNS0:   172.19.41.25,   DNS1:  172.19.41.26
    Subnet: 255.255.254.0   DNS Domain: dyn.netztier.li
```

Oh.. and if you're actually using *.local* as your internal toplevel domain, please reconsider: [What special reserved domain could I use for virtual organization private network?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64785/what-special-reserved-domain-could-i-use-for-virtual-organization-private-networ/)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. It helped me getting to the source of this. It turns out, it just works out of the box. I was using the management port on the device, that does not do this. If i connect a normal port and configure a vlan interface as dhcp client, eveything works as expected. Even DNS suffix works now. I can see my DNS servers in `show dhcp server` and in the `show ip dns servers` command now.